# Create link to email all views results

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that outputs a list of email addresses.

I'd like to find a way to set up a mailto: link that contains all of those as one comma-separated list.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

In the views under fields add "Custom Text" field. Wherein text field you can Replacement patterns from exisiting fields. There you can give link

```
<a href="mailto:{{field_name}}">{{field_name}}</a>.
```

After that edit email field and check "Exclude from display".